# SQL Server - Stored procedure performance issue , Parallelism

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing, database-performance

This is regarding a performance issue I am facing while executing a stored procedure on non-prod environment. When I looked at the execution plan on prod environment, I found 'Parallelism' in it. But that is not showing up in non-prod execution plan.

I did following things already :

1. rebuild indexes
2. update stats

Tables(3) included in query has around

```
10,12,21,751
1,04,29,395
2,16,72,939
```

records respectively.

1. What are other ways of improving the performance ?
2. Can we set parallelism object level ?

Any help/pointers would be of great help.

Thanks

Jony

Comment: [Forcing a parallel query execution plan](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/12/23/forcing-a-parallel-query-execution-plan.aspx)

Comment: Parallelism shows up when the amount of data (the number of rows to deal with) gets large - most likely, your dev/test environment just has a handful of rows, not enough for SQL Server to warrant the parallelism overhead

Comment: Hi Marc, 
Test/dev environment also has the same amount of data as in PROD.